# Typecasting issues, how to use good old == instead of ===

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, typecasting-operator

I really like Coffeescript, but one thing that drives me crazy lately is type issues with Numbers and Strings in if statements. Normally not a problem as Javascript doesn´t care when you use ==, but Coffeescript convertes all comparisons to ===. Is there a way to get sloppy old == comparisons back? I feed stupid but I haven´t found anything on it.

The reason for it is that I converted other peoples code using the brilliant http://js2coffee.org/ to make it easier to read, but then I enter typecasting problems as == comparisons are replaced by ===. Needless to say I´m to f***g lazy to refactor the whole code ;).

Comment: Please drop the tags in titles, greetings and signatures.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no reliable way to convert JavaScript code to CoffeeScript. If you use js2coffee, use it as a starting point. Usually, when you had `a == b`, what you really want is a numerical comparison like `+a is +b` or a string comparison like `"#{a}" is "#{b}"`.

Comment: Interesting to use the shorter `"#{a}" is "#{b}"` and `+a is +b`, I´ve always used the "normal" typecasting `String(a) is String(b)` or `Number(a) is Number(b)`.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham I seem some issues playing around with it, but I mainly have little 2 or 3 line snippets I am converting, so it seems pretty useful for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As asawyer said, this is by design. If you **really** think you need an `==` comparison then you can put it in backticks:

```
if `foo == bar`
  alert 'Sloppy comparison true'
```

Comment: Right, there is always the way of directly writing JS. I wasn´t aware that it´s working just for the comparison within if statements. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 11):

This is by design.
Quoting from the book [CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript)

> CoffeeScript’s is and == both compile to JavaScript’s ===; there’s no
>   way to get the loose, type-coercing equality check of JavaScript’s ==,
>   which is frowned upon by JSLint and others as the source of many
>   “WTF?” moments. Let’s borrow an example from
>   http://wtfjs.com/2011/02/11/all-your-commas-are-belong-to-Array:

```
",,," == new Array(4) // true
There are also cases where == isn’t transitive:
'' == '0' // false
0 == '' // true
0 == '0' // true
```

> To avoid these head-scratchers, you should perform type conversions
>   explicitly

Comment: Thanks for the quote. I´m aware that it is a design decision and it´s a good one in principal. I wondered if there´s a way around this though if explicitly needed (as many programming languages "default" the right way, but often allow the ugly way as well).